# Как заменить картинку по клику на блок на другую и обратно на предыдущюю?JS

Tags: javascript

Сделала только первую замену

```js
function changeImg1(source) {
  document.pict1.src = source + 'svg';
};
```

```html
<div class="uk-accordion uk-text-left " data-uk-accordion="{collapse: false}" onclick="changeImg1('полный путь к изображению/images/img/icon.')" <h3 class="uk-accordion-title uk-active">
  Т
  <img src="images/img/icon1.svg" name="pict1" style="left: 1193px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 380px;"></h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `html` приведите в порядок.

Answer (score 1):

```
function changeImg1(source) {
  if (!document.pict1.originalSource)
    document.pict1.originalSource = document.pict1.src;
  document.pict1.src = (document.pict1.src == source + 'svg')?
    document.pict1.originalSource : (source + 'svg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleImage() {
    pict1.hidden = !pict1.hidden;
    pict2.hidden = !pict2.hidden;
};
```

```html
<div class="uk-accordion uk-text-left " data-uk-accordion="{collapse: false}" onclick="toggleImage()">
    <h3 class="uk-accordion-title uk-active">
        Т
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/100" name="pict1">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/100" name="pict2" hidden>
    </h3>
</div>
```